# Creating a discord bot with python. Cant make the bot do two tasks at once but the code works if only one task is being run

Tags: python, discord

Im new to python so I cant see where I have made an error.
import discord
import os
from config import TOKEN

```
        client = discord.Client()
        
    #Sends a message in terminal if it has worked
        @client.event
        async def on_ready():
          print('We have logged in as {0.user}'
          .format(client)) 
        
       #Sends a message if !test is included in a sent message 
        @client.event
        async def on_message(message):
          if message.author == client.user:
            return
           
          if message.content.startswith('!test'):
           await message.channel.send('test')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(self, member):
  guild = member.guild
  if guild.system_channel is not None:
    to_send = 'Welcome {0.mention} to {1.name}'.format(member, guild)
    await guild.system_channel.send(to_send)
        
        client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: your code isn't well indented, this may be the issue

Comment: your print should be in a single line :print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

Comment: I agree with Salem, the indention may be the issue, otherwise it might be wise to add a little more of an explanation as to what is happening when you run the code.  What is working and what isn't? What errors are you seeing?  I would also recommend using something like Microsoft Visual Studio to catch some of the smaller issues (such as indention) automatically.

Comment: @kevinvi8  Sorry for the lack of detail the problem is that the block of code that sends a message when !test is sent and the block that sends a message when someone joins the server will not work at the same time so if i remove the !test code the join code will work and vice versa but if both are together only one will work. the indentation is only like that because I copy and pasted it into the question area. Thank you for the help

Comment: @SalemJebnoun I fixed the error with the print but it has not changed anything , the indentation is only an issue on the website since I copy and pasted it into the question field. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @BMPRS Hmmm, if the indention is correct in your actual document then I'm not seeing a super obvious answer.  You may want to try adding else: pass to the bottom of your message event.  It's possible that the 'if' statement you've created needs to be completed for the code to move on.